# Using PlasticSCM with Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4, plasticscm

I like the conceptual model for PlasticSCM for games. I would like to use it but was concerned with the issues reported in https://medium.com/@narthur157/state-of-ue4-scm-git-vs-perforce-vs-plastic-dddcc1bb7669 for large content games. What are people's experience? Does it work well within the Unreal plugin for content creators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Plastic SCM as version control for nearly two years in a large Unreal game project. I don't personally use the Plastic Unreal plugin but I do observe people who do.

All in all, Plastic has been a success for us. Regarding the blog post that you linked, we haven't had corruptions that the author mentions. Plastic's user interface (both "Plastic SCM GUI" that's aimed for programmers and "Gluon" that's aimed for content creators) are pretty neat. They offer a lot of useful functionality without being very complex. It's true that there are some things that could be improved in the UI but I find Plastic's support team very responsive. The software has improved a lot over the time we've used it.

When we originally decided to go with Plastic SCM, we also considered Git, SVN, and Perforce as alternatives. Plastic strikes a good balance between speed, affordability, and support for both programmers and content creators.